# Building Blender - single lib folder for many different builds?

Tags: versions

I need to build several independent "variants" of Blender (differently modified sources for the same target platform) and would like to use the same "lib" folder for all of them.
I cannot place them in the same "root" folder with the lib folder (the usual folder structure).

Essentially, I would like to have something like this:

```
MyBlenderDEVroot  
   lib               <- this is where I'd like to have lib folder
   Variant1
      blender        <- Blender sources
      builds         <- build output folder
      mydocs
      mystuff
   Variant2
      blender        <- Blender sources
      builds         <- build output folder
      mydocs
      mystuff
```

I know that I can have differently named "blender" and "builds" folders (like blender_v1, builds_v1, blender_v2, builds_v2, etc.) in the same root but I want them fully separated.

I am targeting Windows and I use VS2013 with CMake.
I have no problems building Blender the "normal" way, just would like to avoid having the same mutli-GB lib folder repeated all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out my self.

There are couple of lines in CMakeLists.txt that set the path to the lib folder **one level** relative to the source files folder (carried by the CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR variable).
To make it work with my example folder structure simply adding **one more level** solved the problem:

```
    if(NOT DEFINED LIBDIR)
        # Setup 64bit and 64bit windows systems
        if(CMAKE_CL_64)
            message(STATUS "64 bit compiler detected.")
            set(LIBDIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/win64_vc12)
        else()
            message(STATUS "32 bit compiler detected.")
            set(LIBDIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/windows_vc12)
        endif()
    else()
        message(STATUS using LIBDIR  ${LIBDIR})
    endif()
```

My real folder structure was a bit more complex and the common lib location was off the branch with sources so I made it a bit more complicated:

```
    # added this near the top of CMakeLists.txt for easy reference
    if(WIN32)
        set(COMMON_LIBPATH "C:/some_complex_path/CommonStuff/Blender/lib")
    endif()

    ...

    if(NOT DEFINED LIBDIR)
        # Setup 64bit and 64bit windows systems
        if(CMAKE_CL_64)
            message(STATUS "64 bit compiler detected.")
            if(COMMON_LIBPATH)
                message(STATUS "Using common lib path: " ${COMMON_LIBPATH})
                set(LIBDIR ${COMMON_LIBPATH}/../lib/win64_vc12)
            else()
                set(LIBDIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/win64_vc12)
            endif()
        else()
            message(STATUS "32 bit compiler detected.")
            if(COMMON_LIBPATH)
                message(STATUS "Using common lib path: " ${COMMON_LIBPATH})
                set(LIBDIR ${COMMON_LIBPATH}/../lib/windows_vc12)
            else()
                set(LIBDIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/windows_vc12)
            endif()
        endif()
    else()
        message(STATUS using LIBDIR  ${LIBDIR})
    endif()
```

You have to edit the CMakeLists.txt file in **each source code folder** (e.g. the standard "blender" folder).

As I am targeting Windows this applies to, you guessed it, Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is I made a symlink in each build folder `mklink /D lib "Path to lib folder"` in windows 10